# Is an axillary bud a type of intercalary meristem?

Tags: plant-anatomy

I have read that some cells that are left behind from the shoot apical meristem constitute axillary buds and that these are capable of forming a branch or a flower.

So will the axillary bud also be called a meristem? And if so, will they be called the intercalary meristem?